# Why is this algorithm preventing my file from compiling?

Tags: errors, algorithms, algorithmic

Wrote a pseudocode algorithm using algorithm package and I get the errors below... Any ideas?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.96\textwidth}
        \begin{algorithm}[H]
            \centering
            % \caption{Pruning Table Generation Function}\label{pseudo:pruninggeneration}
            \footnotesize
            \begin{algorithmic}
            \Function{Generate Pruning Table}
            % \State{pruning_table = [size]}
            \State{Initialise moves}
            \State{Initialise \texttt{depth} = 0 \texttt{ , totalStates} = 0 \texttt{ , newStates} = 1}
            \State{Initialise new cube object}
            \For{each element in pruning_table}
                \State{pruning_table[i] = -1}
            \EndFor
            \State{table[\Call{c.encode_cube_state}] = 0} \Comment{Encode function retrieves index correlating with current cube state}
            \While{New states are still being discovered}
                \State{\texttt{newStates} = 0}
                \For{Every element i in pruning_table}
                    \If{element i != -1} \Continue
                    \EndIf
                    \For{Every available move in moves}
                        \State{\Call{c.decode_cube_state}{i}}
                        \State{\Call{ApplyMoves}{move}}
                        \If{\texttt{pruning_table[}\Call{c.encode_cube_state}\texttt{]} = -1}
                            \State{\texttt{pruning_table[\Call{c.encode_cube_state}]} = depth + 1}
                            \State{Increment newStates by 1}
                        \EndIf
                        \State{Re-initialise cube object}
                    \EndFor    
                \EndFor
                \State{Increment depth by 1}
            \EndWhile
            \State{Save pruning_table to file}
            \EndFunction
            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

[image: I get spammed these errors]

I get spammed with these errors and I'm not sure how to rectify them. It's preventing my pdf from compiling... Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`\Function` takes two arguments while you only provided one. From the [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/algorithmicx) it provides the syntax:

```
\Function{<name>}{<params>}
  %<body>
\EndFunction
```

Since you only provided a single argument, the `<params>` argument is considered to be `\State` (the next token), which doesn't work.

Additionally, `\State` doesn't take an argument, so you don't need to wrap it in braces. Just use

```
\State <statement>
```